# Two IIS Express servers are launched when Angular-CLI .NET app is run

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2017, .NET Core 2.1 and have built an Angular-CLI  project by using VS templates. When the application is run two IIS Express servers are being launched:

- https://localhost:44375
- http://localhost: 52629

I can double check that by examining the IIS icon in Windows taskbar. The first one is that which appears in the browser. Could someone explain why are there two IIS servers? My guess is that has to do with middleware `AngularCliServer` but not sure. I 'd appreciate a more robust and reliable answer.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its really two applications and not just your one application which listens on http and http**s** port? You have SSL enabled, so 2 ports are required

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by Tseng, there is only one application running but with 2 different ports.
If you go to the IIS Express app in your taskbar, right click and choose "Show All Applications"

[image]

You can see that both sites are running from the same PID

[image]

If you uncheck `Enable SSL` for your project the next time you run there will only be one site running via http.

Comment: However, if unchecking `Enable SSL` and trying http://localhost:52629 the app redirects to  https://localhost:44375 and is not loaded...

Comment: If you are redirecting the user to HTTPS then you need to keep the EnableSSL box ticked :-) Unchecking the box in my answer was to prove that the site will only run HTTP in that instance.